# Install Ubuntu on Drive C Only

Tags: drive, c

How do I install Ubuntu on Drive C only?

I backed up all my data on Drive D and I'm afraid that I might lose them all.

Answer (score 1):

Step one, back up all your data to EXTERNAL MEDIA, which is to say, not a drive internal to your computer.  Even if your D drive is a physically separate drive, it is possible that your data could be overwritten, and I would wager that would make you very unhappy.

Step two, install ubuntu choosing the Side By Side option.  This preserves your windows installation, but does not guarantee that some other error, such as a power failure during the automated partitioning process, could destroy all of your data, (hence step one).